# Zotero citation in R Markdown

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, citations

I'm using Zotero for citation in R-Markdown. Does anybody know how to insert the page number in the citation? 
Exp. "According to Smith (2008, p.600)..."

Thank you

Comment: What have you tired? Is this an issue with markdown or an issue with Zotero itself?

Answer (score 2):

The basic syntax is

@smith2008 [pp. 600] says blah blah

Or

Blah blah blah [@smith2008, pp. 600].

For more information, see https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html